# Correct approach to calculating sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im a first semester at a local university - the course is computer science.
We were handed out a training assignment for math, which is not graded yet. However, im having difficulties - i'm basically straight out of school and have never worked with such topics yet.

The task is as follows: Evaluate $$\sum_{k\geqslant 0} \frac{(-3)^k+5}{4^k}$$

I dont want anyone here to do my "assignment" for me, i just want to know the general approach to solving such tasks as i have no idea where to even start.

Comment: Do you know that $\sum_k (a_k+b_k)=\sum_k a_k +\sum_k b_k$ (provided the RHS makes sense)? Do you know that $\sum_k c a_k=c\sum_k a_k$? Do you know the Binomial Series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**: if $\;|x|<1\;$ , then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x}$$

and

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-3)^n+5}{4^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac34\right)^n+5\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac14\right)^n$$

Comment: I am rolling back to the original answer, with $\;n\;$ instead of $\;k\;$ , since I think it is important the asker, and whoever, understands that the name of the running index is completely unimportant. We can as well write $$\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\;,\;\;\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\;,\;\;\sum_{t=0}^\infty\;,\;\;\text{etc.}$$ and change accordingly all the indexes. What is important is that we begin at zero (or at one or at two or whatever), and go all the way to infinity.

Comment: Then you should also adapt the terms of course. Inconsistency might have been the reason for the first editing.

Comment: @drhab Ah, indeed so. I wrote in my comment "change accordingly all the indexes", yet missed that in my answer. Thanks, already done.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped i believe. We'll see eventually :P

Answer (score 1):

Make use of things like:

- $\sum_k (a_k+b_k)=\sum_k a_k+\sum b_k$ and $\sum_k ca_k=c\sum_k a_k$ if the sums on RHS exist.
- $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}r^k=\frac1{1-r}$ if $|r|<1$

Answer (score 0):

In case what you are missing is the definition of the sum rather than how to calculate it, have a look at this previous question.

[Is there a formal definition of convergence of series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753769/is-there-a-formal-definition-of-convergence-of-series)

It includes this example

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i}=L$$

The formal definition is: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $$\left|L-\sum_{i=0}^n{a_i}\right|<\epsilon$$

You can regard  this as a game.  If I claim that the series sums to L then you may challenge me with any accuracy, $\epsilon > 0$ and I need to respond with an $N$ such that if you sum the first $N$ terms then I will achieve your accuracy. If I can prove that I can always achieve your accuracy then we say that L is the limit.  Challenging me with $\epsilon = 0$ is not allowed since I am not claiming that any partial sum will equal my target, just that it will get as close as you like by going far enough.